# I can't find out where did I go wrong in solving: $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{4+z}{(2-z)z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus, proof-verification

I can't find out where did I go wrong in solving:

[image]

$\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1}\frac{4+z}{(2-z)z}\\=\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1}\frac{3z+2(2-z)}{(2-z)z}\\=-3\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z-2}+2\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z}\\=0+2\text{Res$_{z=0}\dfrac{1}{z}$}\text{ (by Cauchy's Integral Formula)}\\=4\pi i$

Comment: You've missed off several $\operatorname{d}\!z$s.

Comment: $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{3z+2(2-z)}{(2-z)z}\,dz=-3\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z-2}+2\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z}.$$

Comment: You mutated a $z-2$ into a $z-1$, and $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{dz}{z-1}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: After the edit, the first integral is wrong. (The integrand is analytic on the unit disc.)

Comment: Note that $2$ is not inside the unit circle, so that $\int \frac{dz}{z-2} = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you break it down to two integrals, take another look at your first integral.  The pole for that first inegral is at $z=2$, but your path is the circle defined by $|z|=1$.  The residue theorem gives a non-zero result *only if the pole is inside the closed contour of the integral*.  The pole at $z=2$ is *not* inside your path, so it will give zero to your integral, and *not* $-3\times 2\pi i$.

Answer (score 2):

You have an algebraic mistake in the partial fractions decomposition. After the edit, the first integral is wrong. (The integrand is holomorphic on the unit disc.)

A simpler aproach:

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\frac{4+z}{2-z}}{z}\,dz = 2\pi i \cdot \left. \frac{4+z}{2-z} \right|_{z=0} = 4\pi i$$
by Cauchy's integral formula. Note that
$$f(z) = \frac{4+z}{2-z}$$
is holomorphic on (a neighboorhood) of the unit disc.